# Why does my C program print "(null)" during execution of tolower conversion of characters?

Tags: c, null, fgets, tolower

I wrote this program to try to understand C a little better. It works, but for some reason, (null) is printed before the correct output. My code:

```
/* This program will take a string input input from the keyboard, convert the
string into all lowercase characters, then print the result.*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    /* A nice long string */
    char str[1024];                               
    char c;
    printf("Please enter a string you wish to convert to all lowercase: ");

    /* notice stdin being passed in for keyboard input*/
    fgets(str, 1024, stdin);  //beware: fgets will add a '\n' character if there is room       

    printf("\nYour entered string: \n\n%s\n", str);
    printf("\nString converted to lowercase: \n\n%s\n");
    while(str[i]) { //iterate str and print converted char to screen
        c = str[i];
        putchar(tolower(c));
        i++;
    }
    putchar('\n'); //empty line to look clean
    return 0;
}
```

Incidentally, I noticed that when if my string variable is added to the last printf function, the problem goes away.

Replace:

```
printf("\nString converted to lowercase: \n\n%s\n");
```

with

```
printf("\nString converted to lowercase: \n\n%s\n, str");
```

Here is a sample output showing the issue:

```
Please enter a string you wish to convert to all lowercase: THE QUICK BROWN FOX
JUMPED OVER THE LAZY DOG.

Your entered string:

THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPED OVER THE LAZY DOG.


String converted to lowercase:

(null)
the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.

Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: I just now tried your prog do not see any (null)

Comment: @Satya, this program causes undefined behaviour, so you will possibly (likely?) see different behaviour if you try it.

Comment: Thanks a lot @CarlNorum for such beautiful explanation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This print statement:

```
printf("\nString converted to lowercase: \n\n%s\n");
```

Has a `%s` in the format string, but you didn't pass an argument to match with it.

You're getting lucky that a `0` happens to be passed, and that your `printf` implementation gracefully handles that by printing `(null)`.  You're in undefined behaviour territory here.

If you turn on some more warning flags, your compiler will likely warn you about this kind of problem.  In a quick test here, Clang didn't even need any flags:

```
$ clang example.c -o example
example.c:20:51: warning: more '%' conversions than data arguments [-Wformat]
    printf("\nString converted to lowercase: \n\n%s\n");
                                                 ~^
1 warning generated.
```

and neither did GCC:

```
$ gcc example.c -o example
example.c: In function ‘main’:
example.c:20: warning: too few arguments for format
example.c:20: warning: too few arguments for format
```

Comment: Ah, the dangers of reusing print statements. I can't believe I stared at that line and didn't catch that. Thanks!

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2012. Not sure how to get it to throw a warning for that.